# Onclick event not firing in IE8 and earlier

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, onclick

'm fairly new to javascript/jquery, so any help I can get would be very much appreciated.  The onclick event fires in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9...but not IE8 and earlier.  What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="url">Item 1</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="info-toggle" onclick="toggleInfo(event)"></a>
<p>Informational text</p>
</li>
<li><a href="url">Item 2</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="info-toggle" onclick="toggleInfo(event)"></a>
<p>Informational text</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#list li p {
display: none;
 }

#list li .info-toggle {
  background: url(../../images/info-blue17.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0 0 -3px 10px;
  width: 17px;
}

#list li.expanded p {
  display: block;
}

#list li.expanded .info-toggle {
  background: url(../../images/info-17.png) no-repeat;
```

Javascript

```
function toggleInfo(event) {
    $target = $(event.target);
    $target.parent().toggleClass("expanded");
    }
```

If I need to provide any additional code/info, please let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Why do you have `}(jQuery);` at the end of your `toggleInfo` function?

Comment: I'm using 1.7.1.  And my noob answer to your question, Ian, is that it works with it and doesn't work without it.  I'm honestly (and embarrassingly) not really sure what it does.

Comment: EDIT: Okay, it does work without (jQuery).  Must've done something wonky earlier.  Still not firing in IE8 though.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in IE8? Can you recreate the issue with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: You seem to want to get the target element. Just pass `this` instead of `event` (changing the parameter to `element`), and use `$target = $(element)`

Comment: I'm getting an "Object required" message in IE8.  Let me see if I can work up a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Ian, I'm not quite sure what you're saying.  Should the code look like this: function toggleInfo(this) {
 $target = $(element);
 $target.parent().toggleClass("expanded");
 }

Comment: I created a JSFiddle, but for some reason it's not adding the appropriate class to the li.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YPKTH/2/

Comment: @user2521958 The answer you accepted is doing what I was saying, so there ya go :)

Comment: Oh, I see what you were saying now!  I just wasn't seeing the bigger picture :)  Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure jQuery code like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("expanded");
    });
});
```

As above code not working for you, pass `this` instead of `event` to your function. Updated code is as below:

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <a href="url">Item 1</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="info-toggle" onclick="return toggleInfo(this)"></a>
        <p>Informational text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="url">Item 2</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="info-toggle" onclick="return toggleInfo(this)"></a>
        <p>Informational text</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function toggleInfo(el) {
    $(el).parent().toggleClass("expanded");
    return false;
}
```

CSS

```
#list li p {
    display: none;
 }

#list li .info-toggle {
  background: blue url(../../images/info-blue17.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0 0 -3px 10px;
  width: 17px;
}

#list li.expanded p {
  display: block;
}

#list li.expanded .info-toggle {
  background: #666 url(../../images/info-17.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to conflict with another jQuery function I have in my js file.  When the other function is executed, then I try this one, it won't fire in any browser.  After multiple days of troubleshooting, putting the onclick event in the html was my workaround.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: If conflict is because of other js library then you can try 
`jQuery.noConflict();` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I tried that (among many other things) when troubleshooting.  Unfortunately it shut down my whole script.  I appreciate the suggestion, but I think I'm going to stick with having the onclick in the html.  I figure the code not working in IE8 and below is the lesser of two evils.  I appreciate the adice though.

Comment: pass `this` instead of `event` to your function. I have updated the answer

Comment: Glad you got this working. For future reference, this method really is the way to go. Try to avoid `onclick=` in your HTML, or your webpages could end up being a sprawling mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleInfo(event) {
    $target = $(event.target);
    $target.parent().toggleClass("expanded");
}
```

My advice is to do `console.log($(event.target))` and verify that it's the anchor tag (or whatever) correct element you assume it to be.

Comment: I just did that and got the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined searchDbases.js:12
(anonymous function)

Comment: Change `function toggleInfo(event) {` to just `function toggleInfo() {` and it should work.

Comment: If I remove "event" it doesn't work in Firefox or IE.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: "It doesn't work" never helps. Use your console, do you get errors? Post all your code, create a jsFiddle.

Comment: I apologize.  As I mentioned, I'm fairly new to coding and am not used to using the developer tools to their full advantage.  Here is the error I get in Firefox when I remove "event" from toggleInfo(event):  ReferenceError: event is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$target = $(event.target);

Comment: I created a JSFiddle, but for some reason it's not adding the appropriate class to the li. Here's the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/YPKTH/2